# SSL read: errno 104 for some users only

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am querying graph api with a FQL statement via CURL which is working fine for all users except a few.

When the CURL request is executed it raised the following error

> SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104

I have a couple of test accounts out of which 2 are working and 1 is not I have tested by:

Making the user Admin / Developer { as app is in sandbox }
Secure and unsecure browsing

The 2 accounts worked on all above conditions but the one not working didn't for each condition.

I was wondering if Facebook have some different classes of Users due to which its happening, may be, no idea

I cross checked the same accounts with other applications and the same result is there hence, I am assuming this is something related to the User itself. Google for it but no success.

Any idea or solution to fix this.

**UPDATE**

Here is the code

```
$graph_api_query = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=' . $this->loadAccessTokenFromDB() . "&fields=name,id,picture";
$graph_api_result = send_request($graph_api_query, 'GET'); ## the curl call 
foreach($graph_api_result->data as $friendData){
    $friends[] = array(
        'id' => $friendData->id,
        'name' => $friendData->name,
        'picture' => $friendData->picture->data->url
    );
```

another example

```
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=';
$fql_query_url .= '{"friends+count":"';
$fql_query_url .= 'SELECT+uid+,+last_name+,+pic+,+friend_count+FROM+user+WHERE+uid+IN+(';
$fql_query_url .= 'SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me())';
$fql_query_url .= '+ORDER+BY+friend_count+DESC';
$fql_query_url .= '",';
$fql_query_url .= '"my-friends-count":"';
$fql_query_url .= 'SELECT+friend_count+FROM+user+WHERE+uid=me()';
$fql_query_url .= '"}';
$fql_query_url .= '&access_token=' . $this->session->userdata('access_token') ; #$this->facebooksession->access_token;
#echo $fql_query_url;
$fql_query_result = send_request($fql_query_url, 'GET');
```

working userID is `656328662`

userID not working is `584488596`

Regards

Comment: What is the fql query you are trying? Also, if you don't want to include the actual user IDs that are failing, you might want to open a bug report with Facebook and include the IDs for Facebook to investigate.  http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create

Comment: @DonnLee added the code and ID